# Dateutil parser TypeError

Tags: python, parsing, python-dateutil

```
import argparse
import gzip
import dateutil.parser
import sys


def main():
userID = "UserID"
previous_timestamp = "2000-01-01 00:00:00"
t_value = 0


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# deze regel is nodig om de file als een argument mee te geven

parser.add_argument("file") # file als argument

parser.add_argument("-t", action="store_true") # argument om te kijken of er wordt voldaan aan de threshold van 1800 seconden

parser.add_argument("-threshold") # een variable threshold, die standaard ook 1800 seconden is.

args = parser.parse_args()

f = gzip.open(args.file, 'rb') # open van de file vanuit een gzip formaat.



content = f.read().splitlines() # het uitlezen van de file en het splitten van de lines

for line in content:
    words = line.split("\t")
    ID = words[0]

    if not userID == ID: #als de userID's niet hetzelfde zijn, dan een --- lijn printen
        print '---------------------------------------'
        print line
        userID = ID
    else:
        print line

    if args.t or args.threshold: # als de gebruiker wil kijken naar patronen met behulp van een tijdthreshold
         if args.threshold:
             t_value = args.threshold
    else:
         t_value = 1800 # standaard threshold waarden

    t_value = int(t_value)

    timestamp = words[2]

    time_difference = dateutil.parser.parse(timestamp) - dateutil.parser.parse(previous_timestamp) # tijdverschil tussen queries berekenen
    if time_difference.seconds >= t_value: # als het verschil groter is dan de threshold, komt er een enter tussen
        print "\n"
        print line





f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opdracht1_2.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "opdracht1_2.py", line 54, in main
    time_difference = dateutil.parser.parse(timestamp) - dateutil.parser.parse(previous_timestamp) # tijdverschil tussen queries berekenen
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 748, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg/dateutil/parser.py", line 310, in parse
    res, skipped_tokens = self._parse(timestr, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can we please see the *full* traceback for the exception? Is it possible that `words[2]` is *empty*?

Comment: Added the traceback :)

Comment: Dank! Can you also add a `print` statement showing what values `timestamp` and `previous_timestamp` have? Just add `print repr(timestamp), repr(previous_timestamp)` before the `dateutil.parser.parse()` line; add the last output before the traceback to your post.

Comment: 'TimeStamp'
'2006-03-01 23:48:15'

Maybe because the first line of the file is:
UserID Query TimeStamp ClickRank ClickDomain

Comment: You need to skip that first line then.

Comment: Jup that was the trick... thanks for leading me the right way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip the first line of your file, it has a header.

Use the `csv` module to read your data more efficiently instead of reading it all into memory at once:

```
import csv

with gzip.open(args.file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip first row of the file; negeer de eerste regel

    for words in reader:
        words = line.split("\t")
```

Using `next()` on the `reader` iterable reads one line from the file, which we ignore. If there are no lines in the file the function returns the default, `None` instead.